# Heroku App with Custom Domain Shows "Empty Project" Screen

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, dns, paas

I setup my Heroku project with a custom domain, and pointed the Namecheap DNS to the Heroku app using the CNAME record. ([Namecheap DNS settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qV4ep.png))

However, when I go to the custom URL, it shows me the [Heroku Empty Project Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WamWG.jpg). The Heroku-generated URL actually does work– at the same time the custom domain is hooked up to the Heroku DNS– and displays the correct app.

I can't seem to figure out what to do next, and there doesn't seem to be any documentation on errors that happen after a successful DNS hookup.

To summarize:

1. I have added and seemingly successfully hooked up a custom domain to my Heroku app.
2. My custom URL displays a blank Heroku page.
3. The Heroku app URL displays the app.
4. I would like my custom URL to show the app.

Comment: After setting the domain on Heroku app, the DNS Target look like `<domain>.herokudns.com`?
Recently I also added a domain to an app and, in the provider panel, I have configured the A record with the initial value of the IP of Heroku app server (<your_app_name>.herokuapp.com) .

Comment: @federicoB you really shouldn't use the IP address - bad things will happen

Comment: have you added the domain to your app with `heroku domains:add <your URL>` ?

Comment: @johnbeynon I have added it that way as well. I added the domain to the app dashboard on Heroku first, which brought me to the current behavior posted above.